# grep -r pattern ./ without recursion?

Tags: grep

I want to run the `grep -r pattern ./` but WITHOUT recursively going through the sub directories.  When I removed the -r flag, I didn't get any output in my terminal.  What flag am I supposed to use to grep for patterns in files in my current directory only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ grep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

so

```
grep fred *
```

will look for `fred` in the files in the current directory.

By using `-r` you are explicitly requesting recursion.

Answer (score 2):

grep  pattern *

also try: grep -l patter * to see which files matched

if you didn't get any output, that means no matches were found.